# FBX file has strange chrome effects in texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, maya, skinning, fbx

We are developing games using unity3d game engine and we are using maya for our 3d asset creation.

We are facing strange issue when we export our 3d model from maya to unity particularly in fbx format.

I we export .obj then no issue comes but if we export .fbx then issue comes.

[image: original maya file]

[image: in unity after import of fbx]

Adding more image.[image]

Comment: There are a couple of things that may be going wrong. First, are you using multi-subobject materials? I think there is a limit on the number of materials that can be imported. Second, check out the specular settings on the material. Maybe post a screen shot of the material. However, the white axe in the right hand makes me think it's the former case.

Comment: Let me add more images.
actually effect in present in model itself so without applying any texture the model looks like chromed if exported in fbx but if export in obj then no issue comes

Comment: Remember that texture and material are two different things. It makes complete sense that removing the texture won't solve the problem. To test, create a new standard material in unity and drag it onto the model. Set the metallic/gloss to zero. It should be normal white without chrome effect at this point. Let me know what happens.

Comment: Hi,I have tried with another material but same problem again :(

Comment: The issue starts after skinning only but I am not able to understand which behaviour is alter default behaviour of model to chrome type effect in skinning process..

Answer (score 0):

In maya try selecting the selected mesh the edit>delete by type>non-deformer history. That fixed this same problem for me.